# grub not showing and rebooting loop after using boot-repair in ubuntu14.04

Tags: grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 after removing windows.The grub menu was not visible(black),but i can boot into ubuntu.So i installed boot repair and used recommended repair.

It downloaded and installed new grub version *linux-generic*(version i forgot) and it told me to select boot device-It recommended to install on all devices(`sda-hdd`,`/boot`,`/`).I choose `/` and `/boot` and clicked 'ok'.It asked me to reboot, so I did.

Now i can not see any grub,it kept rebooting like a loop.What could i do now?   Mine is hp-omni 120 series desktop,2gb ram,500 Gb HDD,dual core processor,2.6ghz

Comment: In your case, you should install `grub` in `sda` and not in `/boot`. Get a Ubuntu live USB and try the method given under "via the LiveCD terminal" in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing to re-install it to `sda`

Comment: i used live usb and again used boot repair. It solved the problem.